# Rails - Authentication Devise - Problem About authenticate_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

please !

I'm taking first steps in Ruby on Rails and I have a problem for to implements authentication with Devise. In short , this is scenario:

I want that the users can register a new user only inside the aplication,  in other words, only after to authenticate. So I used the line of code above,

> authenticate_user!(force:true) for to protect the route of register.

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
 
  before_action :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]
  before_action :configure_account_update_params, only: [:update]
  before_action -> {authenticate_user!(force:true)}, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]

...another methods without modification
```

**And my file routes**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users, controllers: {
    sessions: 'users/sessions',
    passwords: 'users/passwords',
    registrations: 'users/registrations',
    confirmations: 'users/confirmations'
  }

  resources :enrolls
  resources :students
  resources :trainings
  resources :instructors

  # Certificates
  get 'certificates/:id', to: 'certificates#index'

  # Dashboard 
  get 'dashboard', to: 'dashboards#index'


  root :to => redirect('/dashboard')

end
```

So, After this , I can to authenticate and to protect all routes, but after authenticate,
the route /**users/sign_up(.:format)**  for registration don´t working,dont open the form for register, this route are protected even after authentication.
When I  type this route , the application redirect again for dashboard (root).

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Think it's a hard task for a newcomer.

Let me explain why it doesn't work, take a look at the definition of Devise::RegistrationsController https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/main/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb

```rb
  prepend_before_action :require_no_authentication, only: [:new, :create, :cancel]
```

so in your controller you'd need to do:

```rb
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
skip_before_action :require_no_authentication, only: [:new, :create]
...
end
```

This change will basically remove the `before_action` defined in `Devise::RegistrationsController` and you won't be redirected anymore.

Comment: Hello Adam, thank for your help!  In fact  , because this is working, but meu code is like

Answer (score 0):

For me is working , my code is like this,  Thank for your help Adam!

```
  before_action :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]
  before_action :configure_account_update_params, only: [:update]
  before_action -> {authenticate_user!(force:true)}, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
  skip_before_action :require_no_authentication, only: [:new, :create]
```